# Google no longer showing link to cached result in SERP result

Tags: search-results, cache

I was looking today to see which version of a page Google had crawled and cached, but when I looked, I could no longer see the place where Google shows the cached content.

Is this a feature that googles still have in their SERP results? They still have [the official support page](https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/1687222) about how to access the feature.

I'm using the latest version of the Chrome browser on a Mac running Yosemite 10.10.5.

Below is a markup of where I used to see the cached dropdown.

[image: screenshot from google]

Comment: I'm still seeing the drop down in the search results for I looked at.   Are you not seeing it just for your site, or in general?

Comment: Strange, im seeing it show up now for some SERP results but not others. - Ive been looking for the cache date of this link http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-4367620/Roman-mosaics-unearthed-southern-France.html - if you wouldn't mind could you try and find that article in the SERP results and see if it gives you the cache option ? It doesn't give the cache option for me currently

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google hasn't discontinued the feature.   The page you are looking at uses a meta tag to prevent caching:

```
<meta name ="robots" content="noodp,noydir,all,noarchive" />
```

Specifically the `noarchive` in there tells Google not to create a cache of the page in the search results.

Comment: Ah ok, so on that basis how does google handle the page : in terms of including it in SERP results, its ranking, how it will attribute "link juice" to any outgoing links, how often it will re crawl the page etc..

Comment: `noarchive` has no effect on links or any SEO other than preventing Google from caching the page as for as I know.