# Google not showing cache option on the following url in SERP results?

Tags: googlebot, google-cache

Google is not showing option to check cache on the following url that I have mentioned below in SERP results.

[image]

Comment: How long has it been? The SERP can show up before google adds the cache link, afaik.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show the cached version. And what? Why do you mean, it should?

Comment: Related question: https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/107004/google-no-longer-showing-link-to-cached-result-in-serp-result - However, there does not appear to be any meta tag (or HTTP response header) in this result, that would otherwise prevent Google reporting the "cached" result.

Comment: Its been over a month since its is like this. I have checked the site for noarchive tag already its not there.  I am worried because the keywords are also not ranking of the mentioned page.

Comment: Google doesn't show a cached page for all pages shown in the search results -- that's completely normal & doesn't mean something's broken.

Answer (score 1):

Realize that you can have a page "indexed" in Google but not "cached"

If you do a search like site:example.com/fullurl/ and Google shows a result, it means your URL is indexed.

What you're seeing shows that the URL is not in Google's *cache*.

With larger websites, it's unlikely that Google will cache every single page. The example you mentioned seems like a website with hundreds of thousands of pages.

[image]

Google won't cache all of them, or even update the cache very often.

Here are some examples:
This page was cached on February 27th
[image: page cached on February 27th]

This page was cached on March 10th:
[image: page cached March 10th]

Are you seeing any patterns for pages that cache or don't cache?